# Bitwise operations on 64 bit numbers in R

Tags: r, bit-manipulation

A basic question: is there a package that offers this? And, if not, is there a hack that's available using the 32 bit operations?

Comment: Which operations do you want, and are you only considering integers, or are you working with floating point numbers?

Comment: The only bitwise operation package that I know of is `bitops`, and that doesn't work with `bit64::integer64` values or `Rmpfr::mpfr` variables.

Comment: Intergers - bit shifts. I want to convert a page number to an address via what would be  "<< 12" in C

Comment: I suppose I could just multiply by 2^12

Comment: Yes, multiplication would be clearer and more R-like in this case.